# Scrapy - Using the Content-Length header in the Request

Tags: python, ajax, http, request, scrapy

[This](https://www.propertyqueen.com.my/for-sale) is page I'm trying to crawl, and [this](https://www.propertyqueen.com.my/Search/SearchPropertyMarker) is the AJAX request which retrieves the data.

I created the same AJAX request with same headers and request payload. The request doesn't fail but it gets an almost empty JSON which doesn't have any data.

The response of the AJAX request is a JSON file and one of the keys has another JSON in a string form. Since the output is large, I thought the problem might be related to `Content-Length` header. When I use the `Content-Length` header, the request fails with `400 Bad Request`, and when I don't use it, the request doesn't get any data.

How am I supposed to get a valid request from this url?

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.propertyqueen.com.my/Search/SearchPropertyMarker'
    ]

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Host': 'www.propertyqueen.com.my',
        'Origin': 'https://www.propertyqueen.com.my',
        #'Content-Length': 689,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer': 'https://www.propertyqueen.com.my/for-sale?searchtext=',
        'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.513681266.1562266208; ASP.NET_SessionId=utadmp0lcxiobehzff5xpzyl; _gid=GA1.3.1978049576.1562853910; _gat=1',
    }

    payload = '{"SearchTextDisplay":"","SearchText":"","PropertyName":null,"State":"","City":"","PriceMin":50,"PriceMax":1000000,"BuildUpAreaMin":50,"BuildUpAreaMax":200000,"LandAreaMin":0,"LandAreaMax":1000000000000,"CosfMin":200,"CosfMax":1200,"PropertyFor":"ForSale","ListType":"","PropertyType":"-1","Bedroom":-1,"Bathroom":-1,"Carparking":-1,"Finishing":"-1","Furnishing":null,"Tenure":"-1","PropertyAge":"-1","FloorLebel":"-1","PageNo":1,"PageSize":10,"OpenTab":"","MinLat":0,"MaxLat":0,"MinLng":0,"MaxLng":0,"SortBy":"-1","zoom":0,"like":false,"suggestionrequired":false,"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"LandTitle":null,"CompletionYear":null,"TotalLotsUnit":null,"RentType":null,"PreferredTenant":null}'

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                method='POST',
                headers=self.headers,
                body=self.payload,
                callback=self.parse_items
            )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        print response.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Might be that you need to set the content length to your payload's length? Forgive my limited knowledge of HTTP. (the length of the payload in your sample is 689 not 775)

Comment: @CalderWhite I tried with the correct value and changed to something else later. I'm going to edit that in order to avoid confusion. The Content-Length header doesn't work with any value though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reworked the spider a little bit and this generates results for me.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy import Request


class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.propertyqueen.com.my/Search/SearchPropertyMarker'
    ]

    headers = {
        'Origin': 'https://www.propertyqueen.com.my',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-BE;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Referer': 'https://www.propertyqueen.com.my/for-sale',
    }

    payload = '{"SearchTextDisplay":"","SearchText":"","PropertyName":null,"State":"","City":"","PriceMin":50000,"PriceMax":100000000,"BuildUpAreaMin":50,"BuildUpAreaMax":200000,"LandAreaMin":0,"LandAreaMax":1000000000000,"CosfMin":200,"CosfMax":1200,"PropertyFor":"ForSale","ListType":"","PropertyType":"-1","Bedroom":-1,"Bathroom":-1,"Carparking":-1,"Finishing":"-1","Furnishing":null,"Tenure":"-1","PropertyAge":"-1","FloorLebel":"-1","PageNo":1,"PageSize":10,"OpenTab":"","MinLat":0,"MaxLat":0,"MinLng":0,"MaxLng":0,"SortBy":"-1","zoom":0,"like":false,"suggestionrequired":false,"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"LandTitle":null,"CompletionYear":null,"TotalLotsUnit":null,"RentType":null,"PreferredTenant":null}'

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(
                url=url,
                method='POST',
                headers=self.headers,
                body=self.payload,
                callback=self.parse_items
            )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        print response.text.encode('utf-8')
```

I used a normal Spider instead of CrawlSpider and left out the 'cookie' in the headers.

Comment: I still get an empty json with those headers. There is no data coming.

Comment: Included the full code now that I used to test it, and this gives a full json for me

Comment: `{"type":"state","zoom":0,"count":"0","result":"[]","htmlresult":"[]","agentListOnExpertise":"[]","propertySuggestion":"[]","criteriaState":"","criteriaCity":""}` This the output I get. The `htmlresult` key supposed to have the data, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you try to execute it from another IP? I get the correct output on my side: `{"type":"state","zoom":0,"count":"41620","result":"[{\\"State\\":\\"Kedah\\",\\"StateCount\\":252, ..., "htmlresult":"[{\\"Id\\":86755,\\"PropertyName\\":\\"Vertiq\\"`.